# BotFramework Composer: Avoiding unwanted interrupts from LUIS, but supporting 'cancel' across dialogs?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

My bot has been created purely with BotFramework Composer. It has several dozen dialogs. The user's question is mapped to an intent with LUIS; it uses LUIS as the main recogniser. Each intent has its own dialog. Each dialog has many user text inputs, formalised as buttons for the user to click.

I'd like to support a typed 'cancel' across all these dialogs.

I can do this by adding an intent for it with LUIS, and *allowing interrupts* on the text input action. However, as a side effect, all the other LUIS intents come into play, and mess up my dialogs by launching new child dialogs – other than 'cancel' – into what should be a strict linear process. I only want it to recognise 'cancel' after the dialog has been started.

Is there some way to achieve this with Composer, other than adding a manual check for 'cancel' as user input after each text input action?

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?